# SSRS Visual Basic code works only on Reporting services

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I made a parser that rounds numbers in text using Visual Basic code. But numbers rounding works only in SSRS and doesn't work when downloaded (**see average of xxx**)

[image]

[image]

This is my VB code:

```
Public Function RoundAllNumbers(inputText As String) As String
    Dim result = inputText
    Dim patterns = {New PatternType With {.Pattern = "Current Usage (-?\d+\.\d+) is negative", .Template = "Current Usage {0} is negative", .Precision = 2},
                    New PatternType With {.Pattern = "Current Usage, (-?\d+\.\d+) KWH", .Template = "Current Usage, {0} KWH", .Precision = 2},
                    New PatternType With {.Pattern = "Budget of (-?\d+\.\d+) KWH", .Template = "Budget of {0} KWH", .Precision = 2},
                    New PatternType With {.Pattern = "usage of (-?\d+\.\d+)", .Template = "usage of {0}", .Precision = 2},
                    New PatternType With {.Pattern = "average of (-?\d+\.\d+)", .Template = "average of {0}", .Precision = 0},
                    New PatternType With {.Pattern = "Current demand (-?\d+\.\d+)", .Template = "Current demand {0}", .Precision = 0},
                    New PatternType With {.Pattern = "demand of (-?\d+\.\d+)", .Template = "demand of {0}", .Precision = 0},
                    New PatternType With {.Pattern = "usage amount of (-?\d+\.\d+)", .Template = "usage amount of {0}", .Precision = 2}}

    Dim formulaPattern = New PatternType With {.Pattern = "Usage \/ \(Demand \* Service hours\) \* (-?\d+\.?\d*) = (-?\d+\.?\d*) kWh \/ \((-?\d+\.?\d*) kW \* (-?\d+) Hours\)", .Template = "Usage / (Demand * Service hours) * {0} = {1} kWh / ({2} kW * {3} Hours)"}
    Dim stdDeviation = New PatternType With {.Pattern = "standard deviation(\s-?\d\s\*)?\s(-?\d+\.\d+)", .Template = "standard deviation {0}{1}", .Precision = 0}

    For Each pattern As PatternType In patterns
        result = ProcessPattern(result, pattern)
    Next

    result = ProcessFormulaPattern(result, formulaPattern)
    Return ProcessstdDeviationPattern(result, stdDeviation)
End Function

Private Function ProcessstdDeviationPattern(inputText As String, pattern As PatternType) As String
    Dim r = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern.Pattern)
    Dim match = r.Match(inputText)
    Dim inputToRoundedDict = New System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)()

    While match.Success
        Dim inputSnippet = match.Groups(0).ToString()
        inputSnippet = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(inputSnippet, "\*", "\*")

        If Not inputToRoundedDict.ContainsKey(inputSnippet) Then
            Dim parsedDouble = Double.Parse(match.Groups(2).ToString())
            Dim roundedDouble = Math.Round(parsedDouble, pattern.Precision)
            Dim roundedSnippet = String.Format(pattern.Template, {match.Groups(1).ToString(), roundedDouble})
            inputToRoundedDict.Add(inputSnippet, roundedSnippet)
        End If

        match = match.NextMatch()
    End While

    Dim result As String = inputText

    For Each kvp As System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In inputToRoundedDict
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result, kvp.Key, kvp.Value)
    Next

    Return result

End Function

Private Function ProcessFormulaPattern(inputText As String, pattern As PatternType) As String
    Dim r = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern.Pattern)
    Dim match = r.Match(inputText)
    Dim inputToRoundedDict = New System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)()

    While match.Success
        Dim inputSnippet = match.Groups(0).ToString()
        inputSnippet = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(inputSnippet, "\*", "\*")
        inputSnippet = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(inputSnippet, "\(", "\(")
        inputSnippet = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(inputSnippet, "\)", "\)")
        inputSnippet = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(inputSnippet, "\/", "\/")

        If Not inputToRoundedDict.ContainsKey(inputSnippet) Then
            Dim parsedUsage = Double.Parse(match.Groups(2).ToString())
            Dim parsedDemand = Double.Parse(match.Groups(3).ToString())
            Dim roundedUsage = Math.Round(parsedUsage, 2)
            Dim roundedDemand = Math.Round(parsedDemand, 0)
            Dim roundedSnippet = String.Format(pattern.Template, {match.Groups(1).ToString(), roundedUsage, roundedDemand, match.Groups(4).ToString()})

            inputToRoundedDict.Add(inputSnippet, roundedSnippet)
        End If

        match = match.NextMatch()
    End While

    Dim result As String = inputText

    For Each kvp As System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In inputToRoundedDict
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result, kvp.Key, kvp.Value)
    Next

    Return result

End Function

Class PatternType
    Public Pattern As String
    Public Template As String
    Public Precision As Integer
End Class

Private Function ProcessPattern(inputText As String, pattern As PatternType) As String
    Dim r = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(pattern.Pattern)
    Dim match = r.Match(inputText)
    Dim inputToRoundedDict = New System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)()

    While match.Success
        Dim inputSnippet = match.Groups(0).ToString()

        If Not inputToRoundedDict.ContainsKey(inputSnippet) Then
            Dim parsedDouble = Double.Parse(match.Groups(1).ToString())
            Dim roundedDouble = Math.Round(parsedDouble, pattern.Precision)
            Dim roundedSnippet = String.Format(pattern.Template, roundedDouble)
            inputToRoundedDict.Add(inputSnippet, roundedSnippet)
        End If

        match = match.NextMatch()
    End While

    Dim result As String = inputText

    For Each kvp As System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In inputToRoundedDict
        result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result, kvp.Key, kvp.Value)
    Next

    Return result

End Function
```

Maybe the problem occurs because I use class in code. Although I haven't found any limitations of the VB in SSRS on the internet

What can be the reason the code woks only when report viewed on SSRS? I had the rounding code in this report before and it worked. But after my update it works only in one place.

Comment: Why are you rounding the numbers as text instead of rounding them in the underlying report query?

Answer (score 1):

Your VB code is most likely using permissions that aren't enabled on the server. To make this work, you would have to dig in to the server settings and determine exactly which permissions are involved. Based on my experience, this is very difficult to implement and maintain.

An alternative would be to translate this code into a stored procedure in your database. This way, it will continue to work when you deploy the report.

Answer (score 0):

The reason as in the configuration. The ssrs server url is configured in web.config and while the version of my code was **deployed to the QA** env, the ssrs server link in web.config **was set to the Staging** env where the report's code wasn't updated